# What's a Robust but Simple Apache / PHP / MySQL Installer for Windows Vista

Tags: php, mysql, apache

I tried easyphp but i think it's not enough, I want an Apache / PHP / MySQL installer which has the latest PHP and MySQL version, and with curl and htaccess support.

Opensource solutions are preferred, should be windows vista compatible.

Comment: What is an emulator? Apache is A server. Please clarify.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WAMP Server is excellent, easy to install and easy to configure:

http://www.wampserver.com/en/index.php

Comment: It's a little outdated though. The last release was 7 months ago.

Answer (score 4):

I have never heard of a PHP / mySQL *emulator*. What purpose would such a tool serve?

If you are looking for a ready-made *installer package* for Windows, containing everything necessary to install and run PHP, [XAMPP](http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp.html) is probably one of the best ones around.

Answer (score 2):

If you want the last version of each piece of software, and to really do it the way you want, the best solution is to download an install each component separatly :

- Apache : http://httpd.apache.org/
- MySQL : http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/
- And PHP : http://www.php.net/downloads.php

Of course, you'll have a bit more work to plug all those together than if using WAMP or anything like that -- but it also mean you'll know more about how they work and can be configured, which is always nice to know ;-)

Comment: that's exactely what i don't prefer :) but atlast i want any version of php 5.x

Comment: Well, that's the only way you'll get whatever you need/want (except by re-compiling), and knowing how to install/configure the servers and software you are working with can only be a good thing, even if it means spending some time learning, the first time -- and if you were running Linux, I would suggest re-compilation : yes, it's hard the first time, but it's useful stuff to know.

Answer (score 1):

Never heard of PHP or mySql emulators before. To run a php script you will need a webserver and the PHP engine to parse and execute the script. This cannot be emulated by another engine besides PHP.

Comment: i mean apache :) and compatible with windows vista

Comment: I'm glad you posted this as an answer then.

Comment: apache http is a webserver and you may find alternatives like IIS or nginx but this is totally another story. rephrase your question.

Comment: @ryeguy: It's still not justified to downvote this answer IMHO - the answer was correct, and the OP added the Apache information later. Upvoting to even it out.

Comment: @pekka at the time of my downvote his answer was much more brief. I have removed it.

Comment: 4 downvotes :) ! he was looking for a php emulator for god sake!

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using Acquia Dev Desktop.

It installs Apache, MySQL & PHP with one click. Most importantly, unlike many other WAMP stacks, it works well under Windows Vista (32- or 64-bit). And as an extra, it installs Acquia Drupal for you as well, so if you ever want to get into Drupal development, you have everything you need to do so.

Get it at http://network.acquia.com/documentation/acquia-drupal-stack

Answer (score 0):

[XAMPP Lite USB](http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp-windows.html#646)

"XAMPP Lite" is an additional extra small XAMPP edition. Configured with relative paths you can use it on usb devices.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a BitNami developer and I personally suggest to use [BitNami WAMPStack](http://bitnami.org/stack/wampstack). It is free, it also includes phpMyAdmin for managing the MySQL databases and GUI management tool for the servers. Per your requirements, it is open source, compatible with Windows Vista and Windows 7, includes curl and htaccess support and we keep it fairly up to date.